# Notify main thread when button is clicked

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I am trying to create a Popup like this

```
// Create a Popup
var Pop = new Popup() { IsOpen = true };

// Create a StackPanel for the Buttons
var SPanel = new StackPanel() { Background = MainGrid.Background };

// Set the comment
var TxtBlockComment = new TextBlock { Margin = new Thickness(20, 5, 20, 5), Text = Obj.Comment };

// Set the value
var TxtBoxValue = new TextBox { Name = "MeasureValue" };
TxtBoxValue.KeyUp += (sender, e) => { VerifyKeyUp(sender, Measure); };

// Create the button
var ButtonFill = new Button { Content = Loader.GetString("ButtonAccept"), Margin = new Thickness(20, 5, 20, 5), Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["TextButtonStyle"] };
ButtonFill.Click += (sender, e) => { Obj.Value = TxtBoxValue.Text; };

// Add the items to the StackPanel
SPanel.Children.Add(TxtBlockComment);
SPanel.Children.Add(TxtBoxValue);
SPanel.Children.Add(ButtonFill);

// Set the child on the popup
Pop.Child = SPanel;
```

I want to nofify the main thread, when the `ButtonFill.Click` event has been executed, so I can continue with that thread

But how can I do that?

Comment: You can try using AutoResetEvent, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx

Comment: Do you mean ButtonFill.Clicked event?

Comment: It is not clear where is the other thread that should notify your main thread. From the code you posted it looks like it is single-threaded.

Comment: Yes, I meant the `ButtonFill.Click` Event ;)

Comment: @Kimi I mean how do I notify in the method, that the `Click` Event has been thrown?

Comment: @The87Boy What technologies are you targetting?

Comment: I am targetting WinRT with C# 4.5

Comment: What do you mean by main thread? I thought the main thread doesn't really do much other than waiting for `Application.Start((p) => new App())` to complete. If by main thread you mean UI thread then button click events are raised on the UI thread and you don't need to notify anyone. If you want to close the popup on button click then you would simply add `Pop.IsOpen = false;` in your `ButtonFill.Click` handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're asking how to achieve a dialog like behavior, similar to `FileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync`. You can use `TaskCompletionSource` to create an awaitable task:

```
private Task<string> OpenPopupAsync()
{
    var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    // Create a Popup
    var Pop = new Popup() { IsOpen = true };

    // Create a StackPanel for the Buttons
    var SPanel = new StackPanel() { Background = MainGrid.Background };

    // Set the comment
    var TxtBlockComment = new TextBlock { Margin = new Thickness(20, 5, 20, 5), Text = Obj.Comment };

    // Set the value
    var TxtBoxValue = new TextBox { Name = "MeasureValue" };
    TxtBoxValue.KeyUp += (sender, e) => { VerifyKeyUp(sender, Measure); };

    // Create the button
    var ButtonFill = new Button { Content = Loader.GetString("ButtonAccept"), Margin = new Thickness(20, 5, 20, 5), Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["TextButtonStyle"] };
    ButtonFill.Click += (sender, e) => { Pop.IsOpen = false; taskSource.SetResult(TxtBoxValue.Text); };

    // Add the items to the StackPanel
    SPanel.Children.Add(TxtBlockComment);
    SPanel.Children.Add(TxtBoxValue);
    SPanel.Children.Add(ButtonFill);

    // Set the child on the popup
    Pop.Child = SPanel;

    return taskSource.Task;
}
```

In short:

- you create an instance of `TaskCompletionSource`
- you return its `Task` property as an awaitable task
- when you want the calling method to continue, you call `SetResult`

In the calling method you just `await` for the method to return before you continue its execution:

```
string result = await OpenPopupAsync();
// continue execution after the method returns
```

I'd also suggest you tak a look at [Callisto's Flyout](https://github.com/timheuer/Callisto) control for a simpler way to implement popups.

Answer (score 0):

Put a boolean property on the class and inside the event at the beginning, set that Boolean to true.

```
ButtonFill.Click += (sender, e) => { ButtonClicked = true; Obj.Value = TxtBoxValue.Text; };
```

Comment: As I see it I then need to use a while-loop to check the value

Comment: @The87Boy My perspective is from MVVM where the boolean would be announced (so to speak) by INotifyPropertyChanged methodology. Any item bound to the boolean would be notified. I surmise you don't have INotifyPropertyChanged. If you are running something from the main thread, then yes you would need to wait and possibly Thread.Sleep while waiting for the change.

Comment: Oh, then I think I will need to call another method